# How to populate wp-admin/post.php file during edit?

Tags: wordpress

In post.php page of wp-admin I like to populate a post meta while the page is loading. For that I tried the following

```
add_action('load-post.php', 'show_buy_ticket_date');

function show_buy_ticket_date() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ($screen->post_type === 'ai1ec_event') {
        $post_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post');
        $buy_ticket_date_unix_timestamp = get_post_meta($post_id,
                'buy_ticket_date', TRUE);
    }

}
```

Here I fetched the post's meta value. But How can I populate it in one of the field in the form once edit page is loaded / before loading.

For e.g. the field looks like this

```
<input class="ai1ec-date-input ai1ec-form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" name="ai1ec_admin_buy_ticket-date-input" id="ai1ec_admin_buy_ticket-date-input" type="date">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the timestamp to a date value suitable for `input` taking into account that, provided that the timestamp is in UTC time, you probably want to align it with your current timezone.

Finally, you pass the date value to `input` with the `value` attribute:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Helsinki' );
$buy_ticket_date = date( 'Y-n-j', intval( $buy_ticket_date_unix_timestamp ));

<input
    class="ai1ec-date-input ai1ec-form-control datepicker hasDatepicker"
    name="ai1ec_admin_buy_ticket-date-input"
    id="ai1ec_admin_buy_ticket-date-input"
    type="date" ,
    value="<?php echo $buy_ticket_date; ?>
>
```

**UPDATE**:

Given the limitation that `input` is in some third-party code, I would update the field via JavaScript:

Pass `$buy_ticket_date` with [localized JavaScript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' ) );
function my_scripts() {

    // ... get $buy_ticket_date_unix_timestamp based on post ID
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Helsinki' );
    $buy_ticket_date = date( 'Y-n-j', intval( $buy_ticket_date_unix_timestamp ));

    wp_register_script( 'my_script', MY_PLUGIN_URL . 'js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'buy_ticket_date', $buy_ticket_date );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
}
```

and JavaScript (`script.js`):

```
/*global document, jQuery */
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ai1ec_admin_buy_ticket-date-input').val(buy_ticket_date);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: thans but the date format and timestamp to converting it to any iso date format is not my question. I like to populate the field which is provided by some other plugin but they are post only. So please suggest me any template rendering hook. Instead of directly editing the source provided by third party.

Comment: See UPDATE for another approach.

Comment: Thanks Mate. Since mine is back end process so I used `admin_enqueue_scripts` but your answer really helped me. Especially the function `wp_localize_script`.